# Agregar estructuras condicionales con operaciones aritmeticas

Tags: c++

Soy estudiante iniciando en la programación.

Estoy intentando crear un programa en C/C++ que calcule e imprima una cantidad igual o menor a 3 en un precio y que calcule los que sean mayor o igual a 4 a un precio diferente.

```
#include <stdio.h>

  int main(){
    
    int cantidad_motherboard, total_a_pagar;
    printf("Digite la cantidad de Motherboards producidos: ");
    scanf("%d", &cantidad_motherboard, &total_a_pagar);

    if (cantidad_motherboard <= 3) {
        total_a_pagar=cantidad_motherboard * 100;
        printf("Total a pagar: %d", (total_a_pagar));
    }
    {
        else (cantidad_motherboard >= 4);
        total_a_pagar = cantidad_motherboard * 125;
        printf("Total a pagar: %d", (total_a_pagar));
    }
        return 0;
    }
```

Al correr el programa me entrega ambas cantidades juntas y sin espacio. Alguien podria orientarme en que agregue, olvide o que escribi mal en el codigo?

Comment: el scanf solo tiene el  formato para un número. Utliza  scanf("%d %d",...

Comment: Lo agregue al codigo pero ahora me marca error en el ELSE sin descripcion de cual es el error exactamente.

Comment: pon el else antes del {

Comment: Gracias @JuanCarlosGuibovich ya si me resulta el codigo, pero al correr el programa y escribir un numero igual o mayor que 4 me imprime los resultados de ambos calculos. Que consideras puede ser el error en este caso?

Comment: Verifica mi respuesta, es porque el else no lo estas colocando correctamente, no hace referencia al if.

Comment: No existe el lenguaje C/C++. Existen dos lenguajes separados y diferentes [tag:C] y [tag:C++].

Answer (score 0):

Podrías considerar cambiar las funciones que utilizas para leer e ingresar datos. Usas las funciones printf y scanf, pero puedes cambiarlas por las funciones

```
#include <iostream>;

int main(){

int variable;

cin>>variable; //para leer datos
cout<<"Hello World"; //para imprimir datos

}
```

Que en mi opinión son más fáciles de usar.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int cantidad_motherboard, total_a_pagar;
cout<<"\n\tDigite la cantidad de Motherboards producidos: ";
cin>>cantidad_motherboard;
cin>>total_a_pagar;

    if (cantidad_motherboard <= 3) {
         total_a_pagar=cantidad_motherboard * 100;
         cout<<"\n\tTotal a pagar: "<<total_a_pagar<<endl;
    }

}
```

El endl sirve para salto de línea, al final del cout.

El "\n" sirve para salto de línea dentro de las comillas.

El "\t" sirve para agregar espacios en blanco.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios errores tanto de sintáxis como uso de la sfunciones, como comentó Juan primero debes indicar que se recibirán dos entradas enteras desde consola con el scanf:

> scanf("%d %d", &cantidad_motherboard, &total_a_pagar);

Luego tienes un problema con el else, ya que si deseas indicar un else de esa manera la sintaxis correcta es:

```
if(condicion){

}else if (otra condicion){

}
```

Si vemos tu código en esa parte el **else** se encuentra dentro de las llaves

```
{
        else (cantidad_motherboard >= 4);
```

Además que le faltaría el if para indicar que en ese else se debe verificar esa condición. Por lo cual el código correcto es:

```
int main()
{
    int cantidad_motherboard, total_a_pagar;
    printf("Digite la cantidad de Motherboards producidos: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &cantidad_motherboard, &total_a_pagar);

    if (cantidad_motherboard <= 3) {
        total_a_pagar=cantidad_motherboard * 100;
        printf("Total a pagar: %d", (total_a_pagar));
    } else if(cantidad_motherboard >= 4){
        total_a_pagar = cantidad_motherboard * 125;
        printf("Total a pagar: %d", (total_a_pagar));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Por otra parte, no necesitas evaluar la segunda condición, si no es menor o igual a 3 ya con colocar else se entiende que entonces el número debe ser mayor a 3.

```
int main()
{
    int cantidad_motherboard, total_a_pagar;
    printf("Digite la cantidad de Motherboards producidos: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &cantidad_motherboard, &total_a_pagar);

    if (cantidad_motherboard <= 3) {
        total_a_pagar=cantidad_motherboard * 100;
        printf("Total a pagar: %d", (total_a_pagar));
    } else {
        total_a_pagar = cantidad_motherboard * 125;
        printf("Total a pagar: %d", (total_a_pagar));
    }
    return 0;
}
```